# Module not found - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to import a css file in the previous folder,i.e src folder, before the one that the component is in but it keeps on bringing this error, Please what am I doing wrong

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/LoginComponent.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './src/styles.css' in 'C:\Users\Iruene     Adokiye\app-react\src\components'
```

Comment: check back the path to `styles.css` from current file's directory path.

Comment: You have to write `..` to go up one directory. Have you tried `../styles.css`?

Comment: Maybe: `import '../yourFileName.css';`

Comment: Thanks @Tholle it worked

Comment: It would be much easier to tell what the problem is if you post your actual code and file structure you have instead of describing it.

Comment: If your styles.css correspond to this path 'C:\Users\Iruene Adokiye\app-react\src\styles.css' so, you must import with "../../styles.css" in LoginComponent.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import `src/styles.css` from your component located at `src/components/LoginComponent.js`, you have to import from one directory up:

```
import `../styles.css`;
```

Answer (score 1):

if your project structure is like this:

```
- src/
  - components/
    - LoginComponent.js
  - style.css
```

Then inside your `LoginComponent` use:

`import from '../styles.css';`

or named import

`import styles from '../styles.css';`

`..` means "above" folder.

`.` means same folder.